# Generated binary is linked to use system instead of local library

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, libtiff

My build system has libtiff installed in this path:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4
```

And I have built a custom libtiff in a local path:

```
/home/user/libtiff/usr/local/lib/libtiff.so.3.8.2
```

I want to build a binary linked with libtiff installed on my local path. To do that, I use this command:

```
cc -o binary \
    obj1.o ... objn.o \
    -L /home/user/libtiff/usr/local/lib/ \
    -Wl,-rpath,L/home/user/libtiff/usr/local/lib/ \
    -ltiff
```

The problem is after linking and generating the binary, ldd shows the binary is not using the local libtiff, but the library installed on the build system:

```
$ ldd binary | grep libtiff
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fbaf9ad6000)
```

I don't understand why the linker is not using the local library.

I have read some related posts talking about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD or LIBRARY_PATH, but none of them works as expected.

Modifiying /etc/ld.so.conf is not a nice option.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spurious `L` in front of the root slash:

```
-Wl,-rpath,L/home/user/libtiff/usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: Removing the spurious L in front of the root slash gets exactly the same issue. Command ldd shows libtiff is linked against the library installed on the build system (libtiff.so.5), not with the local library (libtiff.so.3). This binary is linked with several local libraries (for example, it also uses mbedtls). The mbedtls library is also installed on the build system, but for this library, ldd shows it is using the local library. Without removing the spurious L I was getting exactly the same issue.

Comment: @aicastell Hm, I'm unable to reproduce the issue locally so can't help without additional info. Perhaps you could link with `-Wl,-verbose` and run with `LD_DEBUG=libs`?

Answer (score 0):

@yugr, thank you for this -verbose tip. It helped me to fix the issue. The problem was with another library compiled locally (spandsp) that depends on libtiff. The configure script of the spandsp was deciding to use libtiff.so.5 (build system) instead of libtiff.so.3 (compiled locally). That was because LDFLAGS was not properly defined before executing the configure script. Defining LDFLAGS as -L/home/user/usr/local/lib/ -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/user/usr/local/lib/ fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your interest in helping with this issue! :)

Comment: Np, glad to help.